# Moving exchange database to another Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

I have to move the Exchange 2003 server from one server machine to another due a hardware failure of the old machine. Both servers are in the same domain. The old machine is defect but I have a backup of the system. The Windows Server 203 machine hosting Exchange 2003 is also a domain controller.

I managed to setup the new machine by restoring a backup of the old disk. I demoted the machine, renamed it to NEWSERVERNAME and promoted it as a DC. I was also able to change the DC that Exchange queries for its configuration. But I have problems to mount the database. In the Event Log I get the message for each database (Mailbox and Public folders):

```
The database "Hostname Store\Mailbox Store (HOSTNAME)" has been copied from the server HOSTNAME to the server NEWHOSTNAME.
In the Microsoft Exchange System Manager, indicate that the database is allowed to be restored to, so that it can be patched.
```

I have changed the ''This database can be overwritten by a restore'' checkbox in the properties of the databases. But this does not change the behavior. I still get the same error message in the Application Event View.

How can I instruct Exchange to use the restored databases?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you're doing it the hard way. I might suggest using this method instead:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997176(v=exchg.65).aspx

This will allow you to move Exchange to new hardware but keep the old server name and ip address.

Comment: The server isn't trusted anymore. To avoid any change to the domain I inhibited that it keeps the name. Destroying the domain would be a catastrophe. That's why I changed the host name.

Comment: I'm not understanding you. Is it the case that you want to move Exchange to new hardware but keep the same server name and ip address? If so, then follow the article I linked to. If not, please explain again what it is that you're trying to do.